# Replace ',' to '.' in template of Django

Tags: django

I have one problem) model:

```
var = models.FloatField()
```

When I get it in template:

```
dict.var
```

I have **`15,78`**, but I need **`15.78`**. I need change var to decimal field or write a filter? In docs I didnt find any template filters, that can do, what I want. Thanks

Comment: What locale are you working with? Sounds like: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/#format-localization might be a good starting point.

Comment: Seems like you have to do your own template filter. Have you tried it?

Comment: Try "floatformat" templatetag `{{ dict.var|floatformat:".2d" }}`